# How can I solve 404 issue using the OpenSea JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, cryptocurrency, opensea

I am trying to use OpenSea API with the JS SDK. I am getting two types of errors. One is a deprecated warning. Another is a 404 error. This is the error I am getting no matter what request is performed,

```
DEPRECATED: Please use providerUtils.standardizeOrThrow() instead
DEPRECATED: Please use providerUtils.standardizeOrThrow() instead
/home/sayeed/projects/SmartxNFT-main/node_modules/opensea-js/lib/api.js:509
                        throw new Error("API Error ".concat(response.status, ": ").concat(errorMessage));
                              ^

Error: API Error 404: Not found. Full message was '{"success":false}'
    at OpenSeaAPI.<anonymous> (/home/sayeed/projects/SmartxNFT-main/node_modules/opensea-js/lib/api.js:509:31)
    at step (/home/sayeed/projects/SmartxNFT-main/node_modules/opensea-js/lib/api.js:63:23)
    at Object.next (/home/sayeed/projects/SmartxNFT-main/node_modules/opensea-js/lib/api.js:44:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/sayeed/projects/SmartxNFT-main/node_modules/opensea-js/lib/api.js:35:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Here is my code following the documentation,

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const { OpenSeaPort, Network } = require("opensea-js");

const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const privateKeys = [
    "private key",
];

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    privateKeys,
    "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/aclchemy - key",
    0,
    2
);

const seaport = new OpenSeaPort(provider, {
    networkName: Network.Main,
    apiKey: "api key",
});

const getAsset = async () => {
    const asset = {
        tokenAddress: "0x0ee7d6519a475a35e5c65dd0193dd1b9800e4db0", // CryptoKitties
        tokenId: "129", // Token ID
    };

    const listing = await seaport.api.getAsset(asset);

    console.log(listing);
};

getAsset();
```

The RPC API key is from Alchemy.

Comment: apparently related (according to a non-answer post): https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js/issues/472

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that opensea-js only has two network options. The Ethereum mainnet and the rinkeby testnet.

In the following line you can see that you are setting your seaport to be using the Ethereum Mainnet.

> networkName: Network.Main,

The returning value of `Network.Main` it's a string which contains the word `main` and while this might seem to imply that you could simply change `Network.Main` to `"polygon"` the sdk will just throw error.

Right now neither the OpenSea API, nor the opensea-sdk support Polygon, but they've announced that for V2 OpenSea API will support Polygon.